# Improving performance when import xml files to android device

Tags: android, xml, performance, sqlite, device

In my android application i use SAX Parser in order to import large xml files (35-40 MB) into sqlite database.
My tablet has a quad core processor (1,3 GHz) and 1 GB RAM.
The file upload around 4-5 minutes.

I need to improve the performance of uploading.

What is the maximum performance of SAX parser (MB per minute)?
If I need to improve hardware of my device what need to change (Processor, RAM etc)?

Comment: use sql transaction for insert

Comment: I use transactions when inserting data into my sqlite database.

Comment: I don't know about Android, but I would normally expect that parsing 40Mb of XML takes something closer to 2 seconds rather than 4 minutes. I would imagine the delay is elsewhere, e.g. network costs.

Comment: 4-5 minutes isn't horrible for a file that size on Android. One system change that would help us to use a device with Android lollipop on it due to the new *Android runtime* having faster garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the maximum performance of `SAX` parser (MB per minute)?

With `SAX` the context needed for parsing is limited by the tree depth of the current element, which means that the memory requirements are greatly reduced, you can't actually gives a specific answer for this because it depends on the situation.

**lets get back to the actual question**

> How to improve performance in this case

You actually have to look at it from two sides as you mentioned above software does effect  the performance but depending on your tablet properties, you need to do both.

**First:**

Take a look at this which show you the [best practice to parse and deal with xml files](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs91/xml/best.html).

it also contain a section that describes in details how to **Increasing Performance of `XML` Validation**

> If I need to improve hardware of my device what need to improve
>   (Processor, RAM etc)?

yes increasing `RAM` will absolutely improve the performance of the uploading process, it may actually effect it more than the changes that you are going to do in the code.

**More RAM equals more speed**